# how to hard refresh page by onclick using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, router

I need to know how to write the code to refresh page by onClick  using react-router

I try to use history.push but it's not work.

this is my code:

```
  onClick() {
this.props.history.push(`/a/${this.props.a}`);
// window.location.reload();


}

      goPage() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.onClick}>
        Begin
      </Button>
    );
  }
```

If someone know that, please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

use this to reload the page;

```js
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: is it need to import anything?

Comment: You don't need to import anything.

Comment: it don't know the window

Comment: it's not work for me cause it's refresh all the time.

Comment: The window object is supported by all browsers. It represents the browser's window.

Comment: You might need to provide more clarity to what you actually want for better solution. Lets see your code.

Comment: @ppppp It may refresh all the time because each rerender triggers your `this.onClick` again. Try to use a callback `<Button onClick={() => this.onClick()}>`